# Googlebot-mobile doesn't look like Chrome Developer Tools Device-mode

Tags: seo, googlebot, mobile

Google keeps complaining that my website is not mobile friendly. Here's what they tell me a random page on my website looks like to Google Bot mobile:

[image]

And here's how that same page looks in Google Chrome Developer Tools Device-mode:

[image]

I've implemented a responsive design for my website, and although it's not 100% perfect yet (as you can see the content is slightly wider than the screen in the second image) it sure doesn't look like Google Bot mobile tells me. When I test it on a real mobile device it looks exactly like Google Chrome Developer Tools Device-mode.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Here are the important bits in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:880px)" href="/css/dropdown.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:880px)" href="/css/mobile.css" />
```

`mobile.css` is an "add on" to `base.css` which replaces the stuff that needs to be changed, but `base.css` provides the "defaults" and is always loaded.

It's as if Google Bot mobile isn't triggering the loading of `mobile.css`.

Comment: Most likely because your using `media="(max-width:880px")` and not using `@media screen and max-width: 880px { }` within your base. CSS exercutes in order, you shouldn't need to be using multiple CSS files. You should also look why your page in mobile is `overflowing` causing the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Just tried using only one single file (I made a new one called `all.css` to avoid potential caching problems) and putting all my CSS in it, with the mobile stuff surrounded by `@media screen and (max-width: 880px){ }`. It works as expected in the browser, but Googlebot still displays the desktop version... Perhaps I should be using something else than `max-width: 880px`?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve it - it turns out that it was a `min-width: auto;` that Googlebot mobile didn't like.

For some reason (to solve an issue on tablets when I first started implementing my responsive design) I had put

```
body{
    min-width: 1510px;
}
```

in my desktop CSS, and was overriding that with

```
body{
    min-width: auto;
}
```

in my mobile CSS. After changing the mobile CSS to

```
body{
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Googlebot displays the page correctly. Will see if I can safely ditch the min-width on `<body>` altogether.